# Best way to type actions with Redux? (flowtype)

Tags: redux, flowtype

What is the best way to type actions with redux?

"Best" meaning maximize readability and simultaneously minimize work required to write/maintain.

e.g. for the file...

```
// @flow

export const incrementCounter = (counter: string, amount: number) => ({
  type: 'INCREMENT_COUNTER',
  counter,
  amount
})

export const resetCounter = (counter: string) => ({
  type: 'RESET_COUNTER',
  counter
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently how I type my actions, it uses the [$Call Utility Type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-call).

```
// @flow

export const incrementCounter = (counter: string, amount: number) => ({
  type: 'INCREMENT_COUNTER',
  counter,
  amount
})

export const resetCounter = (counter: string) => ({
  type: 'RESET_COUNTER',
  counter
})

export Action = 
  | $Call<typeof incrementCounter, *, *>
  | $Call<typeof resetCounter, *>
```

If you split your actions into multiple files, you can then merge all the actions together in a top level index like so...

```
import type { Action as CounterActions } from './counter-actions'
import type { Action as TimerActions } from './timer-actions'

export type Action =
  | CounterActions
  | TimerActions
```